# MySQL : JSON Select Statement

Tags: mysql, json

Previously, I have 2 tables and I'm running the below select statement to get the sql result.

Previous table:

```
create table data_log (
   uuid varchar(40),
   time_login timestamp default now()::timestamp(0),
   browser_info varchar(255),
   browser_osname varchar(40),
   ip_int bigint,
   latitude double precision,
   longitude double precision,
   sp_id varchar(100),
   auth_method smallint,
   js_num smallint,
   fingerprint varchar(15),
   trust_required smallint,
   AAC smallint,   -- Adaptive authentication count
   TER smallint, -- enum ('failed','passed') , -- trust evaluation result
   session_id char(10));

create table cache_ip2location (
    ip_from BIGINT,
    ip_to BIGINT,
    city_name VARCHAR(128));
```

---

```
SELECT city_name, count(distinct sp_id,session_id) 
FROM (
     SELECT b.city_name,a.sp_id,a.session_id 
     FROM data_log a, cache_ip2location b 
     WHERE a.ip_int BETWEEN b.ip_from AND b.ip_to AND a.uuid='' AND TER=1
     GROUP BY sp_id,session_id 
     ORDER BY a.time_login 
     DESC LIMIT 30
     ) AS temp 
GROUP BY city_name;
```

I have made some improvement and decided to use JSON as one of our format data.

The new table should be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE data_log_test(
   uuid        varchar(40),
   attributes json,
   time_insert    timestamp
)
```

My question is, the sql statement that I should use in order for me to get the same result as the old table format.

If you have any suggestion or example of link or tutorial, kindly hope that you can share it here so that I can take a look on it.

Comment: What improvements did you gain from removing your structured SQL columns and replacing them with an unstructured JSON column?

Comment: If no manipulation other than storing and fetching is performed, then the effect is simpler queries... if you actually need to include it in queries, I do not see the benefit...